# Added project to VS 2008 solution; created dependency; getting compiler error CS0246

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, .net-cf-3.5

This is probably a very basic error on my part.  Here's what I did:

1. Created a new C# Smart Device Project in Visual Studio 2008.
2. Added a C# project (Bouncy Castle) to this solution.
3. Created a dependency: my Smart Device Project depends on `crypto`, the Bouncy Castle project.
4. Added some `using` statements to my project:

```
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
```

Compiling the project gives me four CS0246 errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'Org' could not be found (are you missing
 a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I pulled the C# code into the project directly, so I don't know what I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Created a dependency

Nobody ever says that.  Which I'd have to guess is the source of the problem, you "add a reference".  Project + Add Reference.

Comment: @Hans: I went to Project -> Project Dependencies and said that my smartphone project depends on "crypto."  However, I did manage to find crypto.dll and add that as a reference, and it got rid of the build errors.  But if I have the source code, do I need to link to a DLL?  I thought that referring to a DLL was only necessary if I didn't have the source code.

Comment: You don't need the source code if you've already got a compiled assembly.  You don't 'link' it, you reference it.  Linking is a C/C++ term.

Comment: I've run across cases for which library writers offer DLLs but they don't contain all of the functionality that's present in the source code.  I don't think it matters in my case, but I sense there's a way to reference the code from one project in another project without a compiled assembly?  Or are compiled assemblies the way that it's done?

Comment: Compiled assemblies is the way it is done.  The compiler reads the metadata in the assembly to know what types it contains.

Comment: Just an addendum: I ended up getting things working simply by adding the appropriate .cs files to the solution.  Dealing with a third-party library AND not having admin rights on my machine was getting too tedious. An additional benefit is that the included code is a lot less.